# Fourier series convergence question from big Rudin.

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence, fourier-series

I am working on some problems from the 3rd edition of Rudin's "Real and Complex Analysis" and I'm stumped on proving the following part from question #19 of chapter 5.

Suppose $\lambda_n/\log n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. Prove that there exists an $f \in C(T)$ such that the sequence $\lbrace s_n(f;0)/\lambda_n \rbrace$ is unbounded.

Here $s_n(f;0)$ denotes the n'th partial sum of the Fourier series of $f$ at $t=0$, $\hspace{1mm} T$ is the unit circle, and $\lambda_n$ is a sequence.

Help would be greatly appreciated; thank you in advance!

Comment: You could try to estimate the norm of $\Lambda_n=s_n(f;0)/\lambda_n$, it should be $\sim\log n/\lambda_n\to\infty$. I think it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the hint given in the question: use the argument in Sec. 5.11, use the Banach-Steinhaus Theorem in exactly the same way with the change of the linear functionals to ${\Lambda _n}f = \frac{1}{{{\lambda _n}}}{s_n}(f;0)$.
The proof is almost word for word there. 
Again the hint suggest a better estimate for the 1-norm of the Dirichlet kernel *D<sub>n</sub>*.
In the argument on page 162 in Rudin's book, replace *D<sub>n</sub>* by
*D<sub>n</sub> / λ<sub>n</sub>* and give a better estimate in line 5-6 there.

You will get

$\frac{4}{{{\pi ^2}|{\lambda _n}|}}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{1}{k}}  \ge \frac{4}{{{\pi ^2}|{\lambda _n}|}}(\ln (n) + {\gamma}) = \frac{4}{{{\pi ^2}}}(\frac{{\ln (n)}}{{|{\lambda _n}|}} + \frac{{{\gamma}}}{{|{\lambda _n}|}}) \to \infty $

since you are given 
$\frac{{{\lambda _n}}}{{\ln (n)}} \to 0$ .

Here $\gamma$ is the Euler Mascheroni constant.

Follow the remaining argument there to invoke Banach-Steinhaus Theorem to give the conclusion.